# jQuery script in Wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to loop a jquery script so that it affects all the post loaded. The script has a php variable in it so put it in the loop and thought that this was enough but instead it's only sort of applied only to the first post.
Here's my php for the script

```
<?php $valutazione0 = simple_fields_get_post_value(get_the_id(), array(3, 1), true);?>

<div class="postbackrotator" id="rotator-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="height:43px;width:43px"><canvas height="43" width="43" id="my-canvas"></canvas></div>
```

Here I'm getting a value from Simple Fields, it works fine in single.php for example.
Below I have the script with the variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $('#rotator-<?php the_ID(); ?>').rotator({
        starting: 0,
        ending: <?php echo($valutazione0)?>,
        lineWidth: 1.5,
        fontSize: '13px',
        radius: 21
     });
    });
</script>
```

Everything is in the loop that loads the posts but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

What is the proper way to apply a script to all the posts in the loop?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with `id=rotator`?

Comment: One in every post loaded but only one in each post

Comment: An id has to be unique on the whole page. If you use it multiple times you need to generate unique ids. In Wordpress this is commonly done by using `id="rotator-<postid>"`, e.g. `id="rotator-16"`.

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying this now with -<?php the_ID(); ?>, can i then use rotator-<postid> also in the script?

Comment: no, `<postid>` is just a placeholder for the concept. You need to use `get_the_id()` and echo the id there.

Comment: Yep sorry, i noticed later and edited exactly when you replied

Comment: alright, i updated te code above with what i have now but it still doesn't work, any clue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59798/discussion-between-gerald-schneider-and-matteo-pelosi).

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('#rotator').rotator({
    starting: 0,
    ending: <?php echo $valutazione0?>,
    lineWidth: 1.5,
    fontSize: '13px',
    radius: 21
})
})
    </script>
```

Try this

Comment: @GeraldSchneider <?php echo($valutazione0)?>, i think there is no need of () in the echo i do it without them and it works fine

Comment: There is no need for them, but it doesn't make any difference if you use them or not. Both is correct.